# mocking unique constraint check on dbContext

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I have question regarding mocking `dbContext` for the purpose of `unit testing`.

In my below code i am mocking dbContext and DBSet entry using `Moq library` and then triggering `Create` method from `service` and in the end verifying SaveChanges was hit at least once successfully.

```
public void Create_Test_Item()
{

    // creates a DbSet<TestItem>
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<TestItem>>();
    mockSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<TestItem>())).Returns((TestItem testChildItem) => testChildItem);
    // uses Moq to create a TestContext.
    var mockContext = new Mock<TestContext>() { CallBase = true };

    //wires it up to be returned from the context’s TestItem property.
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<TestItem>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    mockContext.Setup(c => c.SaveChanges()).Returns(1);

    //context is used to create a new TestsvcInstance<TestItem> which is then used to create a new TestItem
    var svcInstance = new TestsvcInstance<TestItem>(mockContext.Object);

    var TestItem = new TestItem
    {
        Name = "B01",
        Code = "001",
        ModuleId = new Guid("1F8B2910-C5D4-E611-80D0-000D3A80FCC4")
    };

    svcInstance.Create(TestItem);

    // Finally, the test verifies that the svcInstance added a new TestItem and called SaveChanges on the context.
    mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<TestItem>()), Times.Once());
    mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());

}
```

> I am trying to extend it further to add Unique check. Suppose if I try
>   to create `TestItem` with `Code / Name` that already saved in underlying
>   context, my `mocking implementation should raise an error`.

How I can achieve that through same mocking idea?

Comment: do you want to test that within the same test, you don't call the create method twice for the same item ? or do you want to test that "if an element was already previously existing in the database, perhaps even one that was inserted years ago" it should raise an error ?

Comment: No it didnt i tried that. I have mocked dbContext so my understanding is i also have to mock already exist functionality unless someone prove me wrong.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I was asking : "are you trying to do A or are you trying to do B" .. and you answered "No" :P

Answer (score 2):

Your objective with tests should be to test your business logic, not EF. If you want to ensure that your database is set up with unique constraints use an integration test against a real database.

As far as unit tests are concerned, your business logic might be set up to avoid duplicate unique values. This means that given a scenario where your code would be considering duplicate values, your services/DbContext (if you have to go that deep) can be mocked to expect a validation call to assert that the desired value is not a duplicate.

So lets say I have a routine to validate that a user name for a new user is unique. That code goes to the Users DBSet, it will do some filtering or what-have you to determine if the user name is unique. I.e. `DbContext.Users.Any(u=>u.UserName = userName);`

if I were mocking a DBContext then I would mock the Users DBSet in that case to return a `List<User>` containing a single user with a name that matches the name I am testing with. My code under test should receive that User, fail its validation and my test should pass. I'd also assert my DBContext.SaveChanges does not get called in that scenario. So I tell the mock "Hey, give me something that I should figure out there is a duplicate user name, and make sure I don't call SaveChanges in this case."

To test how your code handles a duplicate ID constraint violation the mocked DbContext can be set up to Throw the exception expected in that case so that you can assert how your code handles that exception. You don't need to go through the trouble of setting up a mock to "detect" a duplicate constraint, just tell it "I'm going to give you one, so here is what you need to do."

So taking the above example say we want to test a race condition (someone else inserted that user just before, or some other developer mucked up my simple .Any() check with some extra filter that resulted in the duplicate user not being found. In this case I'd mock the Users DBSet to return an empty list for example, but then mock the SaveChanges call to throw an exception. (The same type as you'd receive inserting the duplicate record) From there you can assert the behaviour of your code under test. (Does it call a logging service, return back a different result? etc.)

With Moq that would look like:

```
mockDbContext.Setup(x=>x.SaveChanges()).Throws<SomeDbException>("Suitable message.");
```

Again though I'd say that while you can unit test this behaviour, the unit tests should be more about your business logic. (I.e. did it do a validation as expected?) An integration test against a real database or in-memory database can be set up to handle edge case scenarios. The difference between integration and unit tests are that integration tests would be run daily or a few times a day while unit tests with mocks are designed to be run repeatedly while you develop business logic where there is the risk of side effects as you go. The form a safety net around code/logic that is likely in flux. Constraints are relatively static behaviour.